# corda backup node data and syn with newly up network locally

Tags: java, kotlin, corda

I need to preserve previous data once i rebuild and start new network locally. I tried with copying persistence.mv.db and just by replacing new jar but there is mapping issues always. Anyone has idea regarding pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node won't be able to read in any new data from the external database because all the Corda states that are stored in the `Corda Vault` are hashed by the Corda Node for security reason. Learn more about `Hash Constraints`: https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html#hash-constrained-states-in-private-networks

Swapping jars will always create the issue because every time you rebuild your Cordapp the hash is different.

You can learn about Contract Upgrade to preserve the data for production-grade jar swapping/upgrading : https://medium.com/corda/contract-upgrades-and-constraints-in-corda-425055a9a47f